# Calling a COM+ method which returns IStream pointer, activates the COM+ object but doesn't deactivate

Tags: c++, com+, istream

We have a COM+ object and it exposes a method which returns an IStream interface pointer. When a client calls this method, it gets the IStream pointer and this method call activates the COM+ object even if we don't call any method on the IStream pointer and the COM interface object never gets deactivated and hence the object is not returned back to the object pool. But, if we call any other COM+ method on the same object which doesn't return an IStream pointer, the COM+ object gets deactivated normally.

Could one of you suggest a solution for this? how can we deactivate the com interface object after we get the istream pointer?

Regards,
Guru

Comment: The class that implements the `IStream` interface might add a reference to the COM+ object. Probably you have to `Release` the stream object before the COM+ object can be deactivated,

Comment: I suppose this question is about COM+ support for just-in-time activation.  Don't know much about it, sure looks like another feature that made programmers flock to Java.  Relying on it happening automagically when you use IStream is indeed very unlikely.  [Read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686080%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got it resolved by making a dummy method call on the COM+ object:). The COM+ object gets deactivated if we make a dummy method call and the object will be moved back to the pool.